# Read a table from google docs without using API

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, beautifulsoup

I want to read a google sheet table in python, but without using API.
I tried with `BytesIO`, `Beatifulsoup`.

I know about the soluthion with gspread, but I need to read table without token. Only using url.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml.etree import tostring
from io import BytesIO
import requests

req=requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheetId/edit#gid=', auth=('email', 'password'))

page = req.text
```

here i've got html code, like `<!doctype html><html lang="en-US" dir="ltr"><head><base href="h` and so on...

i also tried lib BeautifulSoup, but the result is same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looking over your code, it does exactly what I would expect it to, it returns the textual representation of a page as HTML. Are you looking to get the values of individual cells?

Comment: can you please include the code from your attempts with BytesIO and Beatifulsoup?

Comment: Your attempt of authenticating with `requests` will not work. You need to sign into your Google account, which will be much more complicated. Hence, you will need a large library to do this for you, such as the one you mentioned, or use a public API that Google offers.

Comment: What do you mean by "api"?  Strictly speaking, bytesio, beautifulsoup and etree all have apis.  As does any other library you care to mention.

Answer (score 1):

For reading a table from html, you can use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

---

**If** it's an **unrestricted** spreadsheet [like this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQo1an4yS1tSOMDhmUTGYtUlgnHDQ47EmIcj4YyuIxo), you probably don't even need `requests` - you can just directly pass the URL to `read_html`. [[view dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAHdG.png)]

```py
import pandas as pd
sheetId = '1bQo1an4yS1tSOMDhmUTGYtUlgnHDQ47EmIcj4YyuIxo' ## REPLACE WITH YOUR SHEETID
sheetUrl = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheetId}'
sheetDF = pd.read_html(
    sheetUrl, attrs={'class': 'waffle'}, skiprows=1
)[0].drop(['1'], axis=1).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

---

If it's not unrestricted, then the way you're using `requests.get` would not work either, because you're not passing [the `auth` argument](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/) correctly. I actually don't think there is any way to login to Google with just `requests.auth`. You could login to drive on your browser, open a sheet and then [copy the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q6Ex.png) to https://curlconverter.com/ and [paste to your code from there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOi6.png).

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sheetUrl = 'YOUR_SHEET_URL'
cookies = 'PASTE_FROM_https://curlconverter.com/'
headers = 'PASTE_FROM_https://curlconverter.com/' 
req = requests.get(sheetUrl, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

# in one line, no error-handling
# sheetDF = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs={'class': 'waffle'}, skiprows=1)[0].drop(['1'], axis=1).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# req.raise_for_status() # raise error if request fails
if req.status_code != 200: 
    print(req.status_code, req.reason, '- failed to get', url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
wTable = soup.find('table', class_="waffle")
if wTable is not None:
    dfList = pd.read_html(str(wTable), skiprows=1) # set skiprows=1 to skip top row with column names A, B, C...
    sheetDF = dfList[0] # because read_html returns a LIST of dataframes
    sheetDF = sheetDF.drop(['1'], axis='columns') # drop row #s 1,2,3...
    sheetDF = sheetDF.dropna(axis='rows', how='all') # drop empty rows
    sheetDF = sheetDF.dropna(axis='columns', how='all') # drop empty columns
    ### WHATEVER ELSE YOU WANT TO DO WITH DATAFRAME ###
else: print('COULD NOT FIND TABLE')
```

---

**However,** please note that the cookies are probably only good for up to 5 hours maximum (and then you'll need to paste new ones), and that if there are multiple sheets in one spreadsheet, you'll only be able to scrape the first sheet with `requests`/`pandas`. So, it would be better to use the API for restricted or multi-sheet spreadsheets.